# How to get the Grand Total with shipping charge and tax at onepage checkout in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, shipping, totals, grand-total

In onepage checkout, I am trying to get Grand Total but it  is not updated based on shipping charges, taxes applied instead it is only showing product cost.

After selecting the shipping method and reloading the page is updating grand total correctly but I wanted to update grand total in the step payment information.

Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: Can you please show ur code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quoteData= $quote->getData();
$grandTotal=$quoteData['grand_total'];
```

OR

```
print_r(Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getData());
```

Comment: I tried this only but it will not give you updated grand total, it excludes shipping charges, taxes, etc in the step of payment information.. And if I reload the page at the very moment, then it updates the grand total.
Is there any way so that while moving to step payment information, it refreshes the grand total to calculate accordingly

Comment: edited my answer try that also.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it worked!!
print_r(Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getData());

Comment: Why getting the full data array? What about `$quote->getGrandTotal()` or `$quote->getData('grand_total')`?

Comment: yes you can use $quote->getGrandTotal()

Comment: yes, that the correct way, I just marked it yes because I got a way to achieve that

Comment: @AkhileshPatel: I got one issue there but..while logging the value for grand total, I am getting it correct but while moving to step payment information, it is working as it was working before, not including the shipping charges and taxes, etc..I did cleared cache..
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @AkhileshPatel: While reloading, it is getting grandtotal based on 
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quoteData= $quote->getData();
$grandTotal=$quoteData['grand_total'];
instead it should get it like you suggested..please share if any idea

Comment: sorry, but I am not sure about that issue. It might be need to debug more in detail

Comment: @AkhileshPatel: There I found sometimes rounding issue.
Sometime, grandtotal is coming out as $3.5527136788005E-15 rather it should come $0.
Can you suggest a fix for this, I am using magento v1.9.2.2

Comment: I tried it but I get a false value, 272 is showing in the frontend, but your method prints 267. Edit: It works with `$grandTotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();` thx to shaikh.mushoaib for his answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the grand total by using this:

```
$grandTotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution and I hope this helps anyone who needs it.

By default Shipping is not added to the grandTotal until after you select your payment method. To add it after you select your shipping method go to this file.

**app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml**

The code at the top is this:

**var quoteBaseGrandTotal = getQuoteBaseGrandTotal(); ?>;

var checkQuoteBaseGrandTotal = quoteBaseGrandTotal;**

Its picking up the BaseGrandTotal, so you simply have to switch it to GrandTotal like this:

**var quoteGrandTotal = getQuoteGrandTotal(); ?>;

var checkQuoteGrandTotal = quoteGrandTotal;**

Now your shipping will be add the the GrandTotal, as BaseGrandTotal excludes the shipping costs.